# Like camcorders or actioncams, is there any way to see what is being recorded on another cellphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I have a canon camcorder, and I can use my iPhone to start/stop recording and see what is being recorded. A very convenient approach.

My iPhone video quality is much better than my camcorder, and I like to replace my camcorder with my iPhone for recording youtube videos.

The problem is that I don't know how to control my iPhone with another device and it is tedious to go the tripod and take a look at the display that is being recorded every time. The front facing camera is not an option because of the lower quality and the view angle setup.

Like camcorders or action cams, is there any way to see what is being recorded on another cell phone?

**[UPDATE]**

I'm aware of this [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-camera-wirelessly-connect/id374351996?mt=8), but it is missing the ability to be able to view live what is being recorded on the other iPhone.

Basically what I need is to be able to record video from an iPhone and view what's in frame from another iOS device, almost how a GoPro and iPhone work together.

Comment: Just doing a quick [Bing Search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=remote+control+iphone+video&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR), I was able to find this [App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-camera-wirelessly-connect/id374351996?mt=8).  What have you found and what didn't work?

Comment: @Allan, yes, I know about the app. As stated in reviews "it is missing the one thing I would love. If you could record video from an iPhone and view what's in Frame from another iOS device that would be great, almost how a GoPro and iPhone work together, "

Comment: Questions: (1) does it have to be iPhone-to-iPhone, or would, say, a computer work? (2) does it have to work without an internet connection?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder, any portable device that can show what is being recorded would do. Dependancy on internet connction would be a limitation, but still ok.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder, this is an equivalent alternative to any camcorder or  DSLR cameras. If I don't get an answer here, I have to buy a DSLR that might not record as good as iPhone but has the remote display.

Answer (score 1):

This almost certainly isn't the *answer* you were looking for, but if not it may be useful for others.

If you have an Apple Watch, you can actually use that to view what is being captured within the iPhone's camera frame, both for photos and video. You can also use the Apple Watch as a basic *remote* to control the iPhone's camera (take photos, start/stop recording, etc). Obviously, this only works for the iPhone the Apple Watch is paired to, not for other iPhones or devices.